# Htacess Multi language

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

Im trying to do a multi language errordocument on my htaccess. 
But it doesnt enter to my original 404 error page or it just only goes to one of the error pages.

i just want to check the folder and if the folder is "pt", it goes to the portuguese 404error page, else it goes to the other pages with the correspond language.

i already tryed more example but non have help me.

In below there some code that i had already tryed.

Try #1

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.teleondagroup.com/novosite/Teleonda/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}) $1/404error.php [L]
```

Try #2

```
RewriteRule ^(pt)/ /$1/404error.php [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.teleondagroup.com/novosite/Teleonda/pt/404error.php

RewriteRule ^(en)/ /$1/404error.php [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.teleondagroup.com/novosite/Teleonda/en/404error.php
```

I already solve the problem with this site.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47974/separate-404-page-for-subdirectory

Comment: The Solve Answer is in this Website.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47974/separate-404-page-for-subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if a file or directory doesn't exist in a particular folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0  !-d
#redirect the request to /errorpage.php in that folder
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.*$ /$1/errorpage.php [L,R]
```

This will Redirect a 404 Uri to `/errorpage.php` file located in the requested directory ie . `example.com/demo/brokenlink.php` to `example.com/demo/errorpage.php` .

Or if this is just for a single directory  `/pt` you can use the following :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?pt.*$ /pt/errorpage.php [L,R]
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i tryed but it redirect me to a blank page of 404 error page and not my error page from /teleonda/pt/errorpage.php or /teleonda/en/errorpage.php,

Comment: i already solve the problem with this site.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47974/separate-404-page-for-subdirectory